# Python Dataframe Get Value of Last Non Null Column for Each Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
    ID  2016    2017    2018    2019    2020
0   1   1.64    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2   NaN     NaN     NaN     0.78    NaN
2   3   1.11    0.97    1.73    1.23    0.87
3   4   0.84    0.74    1.64    1.47    0.41
4   5   0.75    1.05    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I want to get the values from the last non-null column such that:

```
    ID  2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    LastValue
0   1   1.64    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.64
1   2   NaN     NaN     NaN     0.78    NaN     0.78
2   3   1.11    0.97    1.73    1.23    0.87    0.87
3   4   0.84    0.74    1.64    1.47    0.41    0.41
4   5   0.75    1.05    NaN     NaN     NaN     1.05
```

I tried to loop through the year columns in reverse as follows but couldn't fully achieve what I want.

```
for i in reversed(df.columns[1:]):
     if df[i] is not None:
          val = df[i]
```

Could you help about this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idea is select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then forward filling per rows missing values and last select last column:

```
df['LastValue'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
   ID  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  LastValue
0   1  1.64   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       1.64
1   2   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.78   NaN       0.78
2   3  1.11  0.97  1.73  1.23  0.87       0.87
3   4  0.84  0.74  1.64  1.47  0.41       0.41
4   5  0.75  1.05   NaN   NaN   NaN       1.05
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:].ffill(axis=1))
   2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
0  1.64  1.64  1.64  1.64  1.64
1   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.78  0.78
2  1.11  0.97  1.73  1.23  0.87
3  0.84  0.74  1.64  1.47  0.41
4  0.75  1.05  1.05  1.05  1.05
```