# Keep the last n real values of uneven rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rows, nan

I am collecting heart rate values over the course of time. Each subject varies in the length of time that data was collected. I would like to make a table of the last 2 seconds of collected data.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

#example data
example_s = [["4/20/21 4:20", 302, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       ["2/17/21 9:20",135, 1, 1.4, 8, 10, np.NaN, np.NaN],
       ["2/17/21 9:20", 111, 5, 5,1, np.NaN, np.NaN,np.NaN, np.NaN]]
example_s_table = pd.DataFrame(example_s,columns=['Date_Time','CID', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])


desired_outcome = [["4/20/21 4:20",302,1, 2, 3],
       ["2/17/21 9:20",135, 1.4, 8, 10 ],
       ["2/17/21 9:20",111, 5, 5,1 ]]

desired_outcome_table = pd.DataFrame(desired_outcome,columns=['Date_Time','CID', "Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3"])
```

I can see how to collect a single instance of the data from the example shown here, but would like to know how to quickly add multiple values to my table:

```py
desired_outcome_table["Last Second"]=example_s_table.iloc[:,1:].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

[Python Dataframe Get Value of Last Non Null Column for Each Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407843/python-dataframe-get-value-of-last-non-null-column-for-each-row)

Comment: Can you explain the logic how the values are being selected?

Comment: Where did the data come from?  I see too many people trying to perform awkward pandas transformations that would be much easier to perform on raw data before converting to a dataframe.

Comment: The raw data an aggregate of many output files. Since I processed it from code that I wrote, it  is in an excel file of a similar format to the question. Awkward, yes, but it's all I've got as I'm trying to learn how to do this on the fly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = example_s_table.copy()
df = df.set_index(['Date_Time', 'CID'])

df_out = df.mask(df.eq(0))\
           .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().tail(3).values), axis=1)\
           .rename(columns = lambda x: f'Second {x+1}')
df_out['Last Second'] = df_out['Second 3']
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
      Date_Time  CID  Second 1  Second 2  Second 3  Last Second
0  4/20/21 4:20  302       1.0       2.0       3.0          3.0
1  2/17/21 9:20  135       1.4       8.0      10.0         10.0
2  2/17/21 9:20  111       5.0       5.0       1.0          1.0
```